# Deriving a class from TextBox class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to derive a custom class called NumBox from the TextBox class and create a setter and getter for this class, but when I run my program I get a run time exception "FormatException was unhandled by user code".  It appears to me that this has to do with this.Text not being an integer, but the input for my program was an int.  The error occurs on the following line:  `return Convert.ToInt16(this.Text);`

Thanks you for the help!

Please find my code below:
default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <glm:numbox ID="NumBox1" runat="server" Style="position: relative" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button_SquareIt" runat="server" Style="position: relative" 
            Text="Square It" onclick="Button_SquareIt_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

webconfig

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="glm" namespace="GLM"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

App_Code/NumBox.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Class1
/// </summary>
/// 
namespace GLM
{
    public class NumBox : TextBox
    {
        public NumBox()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }
        public int Num
        {
            set
            {
                this.Text = value.ToString();
            }
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToInt16(this.Text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    GLM.NumBox n = new GLM.NumBox();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button_SquareIt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       n.Num = n.Num *  n.Num;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've looked into this in a bit more detail and found the cause of your problem.

You create a new instance of NumBox and then perform actions on that. You're not referring to the instance created on the page.

If you don't have an associated designer.cs file then this should work:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    GLM.NumBox NumBox1;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button_SquareIt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       NumBox1.Num = NumBox1.Num *  NumBox1.Num;
    }
}
```

If you do have an associated designer.cs file, then remove the declaration of NumBox1.

Comment: <glm:numbox ID="NumBox1" runat="server" Style="position: relative" /> this is what is throwing the exception and the input is an integer

Comment: Apologies, I missed a line in your _Default class definition. I've edited my reply accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, can you explain in more detail what the issue is.  If i add your code I get the following error: Error 2 Ambiguity between '_Default.NumBox1' and '_Default.NumBox1'

Comment: It's because you have a designer file, just delete the line GLM.NumBox NumBox1 and it should all work.

Comment: To explain the problem in more detail...
You create an instance of NumBox in your aspx page called NumBox1, this is effectively the box you see in your page. Then, in your code behind (the class definition of _Default) you define and instantiate a new NumBox and call it n. This is NOT the numbox you see within your page. You then set the Num property of n which will have its Text property set to an empty string which is then causing your error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    public int Num {
        set {
            this.Text = value.ToString();
        }
        get {
            return Int16.Parse(this.Text);
        }
    }
```

I recommend using the `TryParse` method to ensure you are only trying to parse an actual number. Note that if your `Text` property `IsNullOrEmpty`, Parse and TryParse will throw an exception. You should test for an empty value and if empty, either return a `0` or make your property return `Nullable<int>`.

Also, you *should* parse to the type you are returning. Your property returns `int` while you are parsing `Int16`.

Comment: To supplement this, you can use Int64.TryParse(...) to test if its a valid Int16 or not.

Comment: This is the same exact code as i currently have in the program

Comment: No @Azzi ... you have `return Convert.ToInt16(this.Text);`